# Automating copying data from one Excel file to another

Tags: excel

Ok this is what I am trying to achieve. I have 50,000 items I have in a spreadsheet I need to select 999 items out of one column copy them and paste them to a different column in a different file then have it go to the next 999 items all the way down to the last one.

How can I automate this?

Comment: Care to elaborate better? Can you try to explain with what tools are you trying to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Three possible methods:

- VBA (trivial)
- C# (see e.g. [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/csharp_excel.aspx?q=c#%20edit%20excel%20file))
- Jet OLEDB Provider + SQL (see e.g. [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/excel_using_oledb.aspx?q=c#%20edit%20excel%20file))

Answer (score 0):

There is an example [here - MS Excel: Copy range of cells from one sheet to another sheet matching on date values in Excel 2003/XP/2000/97](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/copy_range.php) that shows how to use VBA to automate this.

I'm not posting the example but the crux of the code is:

- Select the sheet and range of cells in the source and copy to the clipboard

  ```
  Sheets("TheSource").Select
  Range("B5:H6").Select
  Selection.Copy
  ```
- Select the sheet and range of cells in the destination and paste from the clipboard

  ```
  Sheets("TheDestination").Select
  Cells(3, 1).Select
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
          False, Transpose:=False
  ```